# tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose throws TypeError when entering dynamic shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my code:

```
input_img = keras.layers.Input( shape=( None, len(params2), len(params2), 1 ) ) # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

conv1 = keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='conv1')(input_img)
conv2 = keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='conv2')(conv1)
conv3 = keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=128,kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='conv3')(conv2)
conv4 = keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=256,kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='conv4')(conv3)

convlstm1 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, return_sequences=True, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='convlstm1')(conv1)
convlstm2 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, return_sequences=True, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='convlstm2')(conv2)
convlstm3 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=128,return_sequences=True, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='convlstm3')(conv3)
convlstm4 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=256,return_sequences=True, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='convlstm4')(conv4)

deconv4 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='valid', output_padding=(0, -1, -1), data_format='channels_last', name='deconv4')(convlstm4)
concat4 = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4, name='concat4')([convlstm3, deconv4])
deconv3 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=64 , kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='valid', output_padding=(0, -1, -1), data_format='channels_last', name='deconv3')(concat4)
concat3 = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4, name='concat3')([convlstm2, deconv3])
deconv2 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=32 , kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='same' , data_format='channels_last', name='deconv2')(concat3)
concat2 = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4, name='concat2')([convlstm1, deconv2])
deconv1 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=1  , kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same' , data_format='channels_last', name='deconv1')(concat2)

autoencoder = keras.models.Model(input_img, deconv1)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()
```

Without problem, this should send me an summary of the framework. But here is the error message that I've got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-83622ca7a77b> in <module>
     28     return autoencoder
     29 
---> 30 autoencoder1(1700)

<ipython-input-150-83622ca7a77b> in autoencoder1(file_length)
     14     convlstm4 = keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=256,return_sequences=True, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='selu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name='convlstm4')(conv4)
     15 
---> 16     deconv4 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='valid', output_padding=(0, -1, -1), data_format='channels_last', name='deconv4')(convlstm4)
     17     concat4 = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4, name='concat4')([convlstm3, deconv4])
     18     deconv3 = keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=64 , kernel_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2), activation='selu', padding='valid', output_padding=(0, -1, -1), data_format='channels_last', name='deconv3')(concat4)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    552             # In graph mode, failure to build the layer's graph
    553             # implies a user-side bug. We don't catch exceptions.
--> 554             outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    555           else:
    556             try:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
   1138       else:
   1139         outputs_4d = array_ops.reshape(outputs, [
-> 1140             outputs_shape[0], outputs_shape[1] * outputs_shape[2],
   1141             outputs_shape[3], outputs_shape[4]
   1142         ])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

People said that this bug has been solved in 2018, but I'm not sure why there is still an error message here.

Comment: According to [the associated GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25978) this has (or has not) been fixed only in February of this year. Which version of TensorFlow are you running?

Comment: Hi. My Tensorflow version is 1.13.1. Which Tensorflow version do you suggest me?

Comment: As you have seen on GitHub, this should have been fixed in 1.13.1. I suggest you wait for the response of the TF dev team.